# Shuffle loop Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
def mainpage(request):

    ads_right = Ads.objects.select_related().all().filter(ads_section = 'R')
    ads_left = Ads.objects.select_related().all().filter(ads_section = 'L')

    variables = RequestContext(request, {'ads_right': ads_right,'ads_left': ads_left})
    return render_to_response('index.html', variables)
```

Can you please answer template tag , how to shuffle 'ads_right' and 'ads_left' on each refresh .

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle them in your views:

```
ads_right = Ads.objects.select_related().all().filter(ads_section = 'R').order_by('?')
ads_left = Ads.objects.select_related().all().filter(ads_section = 'L').order_by('?')

# return things as always
variables = RequestContext(request, {'ads_right': ads_right,'ads_left': ads_left})
return render_to_response('index.html', variables)
```

If you want a templatetag, you could use something like this:

```
@register.filter
def shuffle(arg):
    # slice it, cast it to list
    my_list = list(arg[:])
    random.shuffle(my_list)
    return my_list
```

And then in the templates:

```
{% for item in ads_left|shuffle %}
```

Comment: did i wanna use a template tag if i'm 

using 


# shuffling
random.shuffle(ads_right)
random.shuffle(ads_left)

on views

Comment: 'QuerySet' object doestnot support item assignment

Comment: you must cast them to list before, I even wrote it. Also, if you shuffle them in your view, you don't need a templatetag anymore

Comment: 'QuerySet' object doestnot support item assignmen

Comment: Changed a bit the first solution, using something I don't like much `order_by('?')` (the random operator is going to become overkill if it's working on big tables)